# How to collect a list of file URLs using Rules and send a single email containing that list?

Tags: 7, rules, files, emails

I am using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to send an email when a content node gets saved/updated.

I have a basic node where users can upload a large number of files and enter an email address to notify someone about the change.

In this example, the Rules Action to <kbd>Send Email</kbd> is in a Rules loop, and I get one email per item in list. When I move <kbd>Send Email</kbd> to the left, I cannot access the "`list_item`" variable.

**Rules Events**:

- After saving new content
- After updating existing content

**Rules Conditions**:

- *Content is of type*, Parameter: Content: [node], Content types: BasicPage
- *NOT Data value is empty*, Parameter: Data to check: [node:field-email]

**Rules Actions**:

- *Loop*
- Parameter: List: [node:field-file]
- List item: Current list item (list_item)

  - *Send Email*
  - Parameter: To: [node:field-email], Subject: Test [node:title], Message: [list-item:file:url], From: noreply@host.ca

Comment: Merci for the (late) accept, better late then never, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problems with what you tried so far

> the Rules Action to <kbd>Send Email</kbd> is in a Rules loop, and I get one email per item in list

Your rule works as implemented: for each iteration of your loop, you have a <kbd>Send an eMail</kbd> action ... That's not really what you want of course ...

> When I move <kbd>Send Email</kbd> to the left, I cannot access the "`list_item`" variable.

With that "*move Email to the left*", you must mean something like "***Using the Rules UI, I change the Rules Action to <kbd>Send an eMail</kbd>, so that it is no longer considered as one of the Rules Actions to be performed for each iteration of the loop. And instead that <kbd>Send an eMail</kbd> Rules Action should only be performed 1 time after the Rules loop is completed finished***".

So yes, that's a way to only execute such <kbd>Send an eMail</kbd> Rules Action 1 time (instead of for each iteration of the loop). However, by doing so, your Rules Action to <kbd>Send an eMail</kbd> no longer has access to that crucial variable `list_item` which is like a local variable inside your loop.

### Solution to make it work anyway

However, if what you're looking for (= the list of files as stored in your file field) is not available, then just (a) make it available first and (b) wait with your <kbd>Send an eMail</kbd> action until it is available. Read on for more details ...

**The trick to do so** is similar to what is shown in the Rules example included in my answer to "[How to concatenate all token values of a list in a single field within a Rules loop?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/221244/39516)". In your case, you could make it work like so:

1. **Add** some new Rules variable that will be used later on as part of the eMail body, before the start of your loop. Say you name the variable `file_list_var_for_email_body`.
2. Within your loop, for each iteration, prepend or append the value for each `list_item` to that variable `file_list_var_for_email_body` (see where we're going???).
3. Move that <kbd>Send an eMail</kbd> action outside your loop, and after the loop completed. And finetune the details (configuration) of your Rules Action to <kbd>Send an eMail</kbd>. When doing so, you'll be able to select the token for `file_list_var_for_email_body` to include anywhere in your eMail body.

***Easy, no?***

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating text in Rules was difficult when I did it. What I did was to keep two variables: a text array with a starting element value (such as "This is a digest:...") and a text value.

For each iteration of a loop over items to concatenate into a digest, etc. I set the text value to be the first item in the array ([array:0]) and then set the [array:0] value to be a concatenation of the text value and the new value from the loop. When the loop finishes, you know the [array:0] has the digest content.

I do not know why this couldn't work in a simpler way by concatenating the text value each loop directly or using two text values instead of an array. When I tried either of the other ways it only kept the last item or first item of what was being concatenated.